# Fit a pair of curves to each other

Tags: optimization, regression, interpolation, curves

I may probably use the wrong terms, but I hope you still get the point:

I have 2 curves $c_j, j=1,2$ defined by $(Y_{i,j} , X_{i,j}) , i=1,\ldots,N$ with $X_{i,j} \in [a , b]$ with $X_{i,1} = X_{i,2}$ (but I'd probably like to know for $X_{i,1} \neq X_{i,2}$ as well if there might be different way than interpolation). I want to know the factor in y $q_y$ and the shift in x $d_x$ to make $c_1$ overlap with $c_2$.

To be more specific: I have 2 curves which should overlap within a certain region but don't actually do. I would like to know the factor of x shift and y stretch to correct the whole curves c_1 and c_2 also outside the overlap region.

One way to accomplish this is searching a minimum of squared distance or a covariance of 1 for several shifts and factors applied, but I thought there might be some more analytical way to retrieve the desired factors like some kind of linear regression.

I hope I made it clear and that you might have the simple solution I do not see know.
Thanks

**EDIT:**

I am asking for translation and scaling. As requested I prepared an example in R. Code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)

y <- function(x0, dx=0, qy=1)
{
  x <- x0 + dx
  (sin(x) - 0.2*x + 10) * qy + rnorm(length(x),sd=0.1)
}

x <- seq(20,30,0.1)
y1 <- y(x)
y2 <- y(x,0.5,0.9)

df <- data.frame(x=rep(x,2),
                 y=c(y1,y2),
                 curve=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),each=length(x)))
                 )

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=curve))
p <- p + geom_line()
p

ggsave("example.png",p)
```

In this example I used a list of $x \in [20,30]$ for curves $y_1$ and $y_2$. I **do not have** the function $y = sin(x) - 0.2 x + 10$. this is just for demonstration.

This creates the following plot (sorry too little reputation for showing here):
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sXyl.png)

So what I have is: $x, y_1$ and $y_2$

what I want to find out:

- $dx$ ... unknown translation in $x$ for $y_2$
- $q_y$ ... unknown scaling from $y_1$ to $y_2$ without the translation $dx$

Comment: Do you want to translate Yi,2 (i.e., Yi,2 = Yi,2 + qy) or scale Yi,2 (i.e., Yi,2=qy*Yi,2)?

Comment: @ Martin : One little picture says more than a long speech!

Comment: Are the points in correspondence ?

Comment: I'm sorry I have never heard the term "to be in correspondence". Can you explain what you mean? Probably this helps... actually both curves may be defined by a different amount of points. But they will be in the same x-range (meaning they have an overlap region in x which is greater than the unknown x shift $dx$). For simplicity I thought of interpolating the $y_2$ to the x-values of $y_1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idea to solve the problem. I didn't test it. So, don't ask me to elaborate.

Notations:

The discretized first curve is defined by the points:
$\quad (X_1,Y_1),(X_2,Y_2),...$

These points are supposed to be close to an unknown function $Y(x)$.

The discretized second curve is defined by the points:
$\quad (x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...$

These points are supposed to be close to an unknown function $y(x)$.

it is supposed that those functions are related by an $x$ shift and an $y$ stretch so that 
$$y(x)=a\:Y(x-b)$$
where $a$ is the unknown stretch factor and $b$ is the unknown shift parameter.

Proposed method of calculus :

Consider the Fourier transform of the functions $Y(x)$ and $y(x)$, respectively
$$G(\omega)=\mathscr{\LARGE{F}}\big(Y(x);\omega\big)$$
$$g(\omega)=\mathscr{\LARGE{F}}\big(y(x);\omega\big)$$
Numerical calculus of the Fourier transforms will lead to the transform data, respectively :
$$(G_1,\omega_1), (G_2,\omega_2), ... \quad\text{ and }\quad (g_1,\omega_1), (g_2,\omega_2), ...$$
where the $G$ and $g$ are complex numbers.

It is known that
$$\mathscr{\LARGE{F}}\big(Y(x-b);\omega\big)=e^{i\,b\,\omega}\mathscr{\LARGE{F}}\big(Y(x);\omega\big) $$
The Fourier transform of $y(x)=a\:Y(x-b)$ is :
$$g(\omega)=a\,e^{i\,b\,\omega}G(\omega)$$

$$g(\omega)=G(\omega)a\left(\cos(b\omega)+i\,\sin(b\omega)\right)$$
Separating the real and imaginary parts, with the above data, a non-linear regression leads to approximate values of the parameters $a$ and $b$.

IN ADDITION:

I made a few tests of the above method. For example, with the same generative function that Martin used. But the simulated scatter isn't exactly the same because all softwares have not the same random function. So, the curves red and blue on the figure below are not the exact copy of the Martin's graph.

The resulting stretched and translated curve is drawn in black (this is the red cuve transformed to approximately fit to the blue curve).

[image]

The computed stretch factor $0.868$ is to be compared to the theoretical $0.9$

The computed shift on x-axis $-0.413$ is to be compared to the theoretical $-0.5$ which isn't very good.

It appears that the result is very sensitive to the level of scatter of the original data. The method seems rather robust for the computation of the stretch factor. But very bad about the x-shift computation.

As a consequence, on practical viewpoint, this method is too sensitive to the scatter of data and not robust enough.  I don't advise to use it until serious improvement would be achieved. This probably would require a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I agree in the first part of your answer. The formula $y(x)=aY(x−b)$ describes my problem correctly. I want to find $a$ and $b$. I would assume the "unknown" functions to be interpolated between the known points. The second part is a little bit complex for theoretically knowing if this solves my problem. I will try to check as soon as possible

Comment: @Martin : Don't spent much time with this method of Fourier transform. My tests show that it isn't reliable enough (see the addition to my first answer). Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Martin's demonstration plot showing the two curves:

[image: OP data]

Assumption: two data sets of the form sharing the same measurement locations $x$:
$\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$ and
$\left\{ x_{k}, z_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$ with

Shift and scale the $y$ data points to best fit the $z$ data points, represented by the trial function:
$$
 z = a_{0} + a_{1} y.
$$
The linear system is
$$
%
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} a &= z \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & y_{1} \\
 1 & y_{2} \\
 \vdots & \vdots \\
 1 & y_{m}
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 a_{0} \\
 a_{1}
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
 z_{1} \\
 z_{2} \\
 \vdots \\
 z_{m}
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$
Solutions for solving this linear system are rife throughout this site. If you can't find one, post a comment.

Comment: putting it into a matrix equation is an interesting approach, but either I misunderstand you or you missunderstood me. I want an x-shift and a y-scale. I think your equation $z = a_0 + a_1 y$ represents a y-shift and y-scale, additionally the system $A a = z$ seems to be over-determined, as I have all ys and zs. Did I get you wrong?

Comment: @dantopa. I an afraid that you made a mistake in your equation $z=a_0+a_1y$ : you assumed that the k-th point $(x_k,y_k)$ of the first curve goes to the k-th point $(x_k,z_k)$ of the second curve. This is false. When you skew and translate the first cuve, the point $(x_k,y_k)$ goes to a point with a different abscissa, say $x_i$. So, it goes to the point  $(x_i,z_i)$ of the second curve. Thus, the equation is :$$z_i=a_0+a_1y_k$$ and you cannot built a so simple matrix equation as you did: The relationship between $k$ and $i$ isn't known. If it was know, the problem would be immediately solved.